# How to correctly configure cepheus cep to recalculate a attribute every hour?

Tags: fiware, complex-event-processing, esper

Let me explain it a bit more.
I have this cep config:

```
{
  "host":"http://localhost:1028", //Cepheus CEP
  "in":[
    {
      "id":"A.*",
      "type":"Pevent",
      "isPattern":true,
      "providers":[
        "http://localhost:1027" //Cepheus Broker
      ],
      "attributes":[
         { "name":"idEvent", "type":"string" },
         { "name":"endDate", "type":"date" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "out":[
    {
      "id":"A",
      "type":"Event",
      "brokers":[
        {
          "url":"http://localhost:1026" //orion
        }
      ],
      "attributes":[
         { "name":"expired", "type":"int" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "statements":[
     "INSERT INTO Event SELECT idEvent as id, case when endDate<current_timestamp() then 1 else 0 end as expired FROM Pevent OUTPUT all"
  ]
}
```

This config when new entity is aded or modified in cepheus context broker, it notifies cepheus cep and cep calculates if the entity is expired or not and send the result to orion.This is working ok with no problem.

The problem now is that I need to recalculate the expired attribute one time per hour (24h a day 365 day a year continuoly) and i don't know if it is possible in cep because I can't make it work and don't find any info.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second rule for detecting the expired event.

You can use [Esper Patterns](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.4.0/esper-reference/html/event_patterns.html) to detect that an event has **not** occurred over a period of time:

```
SELECT e.id as id, 1 as expired FROM pattern[every e=Pevent -> (timer:interval(1 hour) and not Pevent(id = e.id)]
```

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. It works perfect. thanks a lot.

Comment: Well after working in other things I realize that you answer don't satisfied  my needs it only do it ones in an hour or the interval specified. I try doing this `SELECT e.id as id, 1 as expired FROM pattern[every timer:interval(1 hour) and e=Pevent -> (not Pevent(id = e.id)]` and it works the way i want but it gets stuck with the first event only in the timer ( console only  show [Timer-default-0] with event 1 even i sent event 2 and 3). How could i make it do the same with all the Events in?

Comment: Well, maybe you should edit your initial request with a new description of what you want to achieve. The answer I provided was to match your initial request.

Comment: the problem is the same but it have to do it 24 times (1 time per hour) in the day for the 365 days of a year. Thanks for the help hope that I explained it better this time.

Comment: This might be possible with Esper, but looks like you be better going with a cron job executing a query against a database. You might achieve what you want with an `on pattern` clause and `timer:at` pattern but is seems like a wrong use case for a CEP.